# SQL insert into 2 tables in one query

Tags: sql, database, db2, ibm-midrange

I have the following query in SQLRPGLE for DB2:

```
    INSERT INTO ITEMS2 (PROGRAM, VLDFILE, VLDFLD, 
    SELFILE, SELFLD) VALUES(:SCAPP   , 'CSTMR', 'CYC',
    'BYC', 'BYCC');
```

I would like this query to be run in 2 libraries as in FIRST/ITEMS2 and SECOND/ITEMS2

where FIRST and SECOND are the library names. Can this be achieved in one query?

For those who have no understanding of iSeries: The above insert statement would be similar to  having a insert query for 2 tables.

Answer (score 2):

The [INSERT](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/db2/rbafzbackup.htm) statement does not support inserting into multiple tables.

However you could create a trigger on `FIRST/ITEMS2` to automatically insert/update/delete the record into `SECOND/ITEMS2`.

See the [CREATE TRIGGER](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/db2/rbafzhctrigger.htm) statement for more information.

Answer (score 1):

If this will be run often, consider making the INSERT into a stored procedure, and then setting the target schema via SET SCHEMA:

```
set schema=first;
call my_insert_proc(:scapp);
set schema=second;
call my_insert_proc(:scapp);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a QMQuery like this

```
    INSERT INTO &LIB/ITEMS2 
             (PROGRAM, VLDFILE, VLDFLD, SELFILE, SELFLD)
      VALUES (&SCAPP, 'CSTMR',  'CYC',  'BYC',   'BYCC');
```

Then

```
STRQMQRY myQmQry  SETVAR(('LIB' 'FIRSTLIB')('SCAPP' &VAR))
STRQMQRY myQmQry  SETVAR(('LIB' 'SECONDLIB')('SCAPP' &VAR))
```

Answer (score 0):

From IBM's Syntax diagram of `INSERT` ( http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fdb2%2Frbafzbackup.htm ), I'd say you have to go with two queries.

But after the first time of executing this query, you can try changing the current library ( http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iadthelp/v7r1/topic/com.ibm.etools.iseries.langref2.doc/chglibl.html ).

Comment: The DB2 reference cited here is for mainframe DB2 10, not DB2 for i.  Wouldn't SET SCHEMA be a better choice that dropping back to the OS and issuing a CHGLIBL?